# Missing 'ammintrin.h' when compiling Hadoop on Windows?

Tags: windows, hadoop, build, midl

UPDATE-2 
I have updated the Windows SDK compilers and now have reduced the errors to 2.

```
  c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\intrin.h(26): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'ammintrin.h': No such file or directory [C:\hadoop-2.7.0-src\hadoop-common-project\hadoop-common\src\main\native\native.vcxproj]
```

now where ever I have searched, I have found that to get this .h file I need to install the Microsoft Visual Studio Service Pack 1. I don't have Visual Studio, I am using Windows SDK 7.1. Now, where can I find the equivalent Service Pack 1 for Windows SDK 7.1?
UPDATE-2 END

UPDATE 
After staring at the stack trace for sometime I see that the error occurs here

```
Midl:
  C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Bin\midl.exe /W2 /WX /nologo /char signed /env x64 /Oicf /app_config /out"C:\hadoop-2.7.0-src\hadoop-common-project\hadoop-common\target/winutils/" /h "hadoopwinutilsvc_h.h" /tlb "C:\hadoop-2.7.0-src\hadoop-common-project\hadoop-common\target/winutils/libwinutils.tlb" /robust hadoopwinutilsvc.idl 
TRACKER : error TRK0002: Failed to execute command: ""C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Bin\midl.exe" /W2 /WX /nologo /char signed /env x64 /Oicf /app_config /outC:\hadoop-2.7.0-src\hadoop-common-project\hadoop-common\target/winutils/ /h hadoopwinutilsvc_h.h /tlb C:\hadoop-2.7.0-src\hadoop-common-project\hadoop-common\target/winutils/libwinutils.tlb /robust hadoopwinutilsvc.idl". The handle is invalid. [C:\hadoop-2.7.0-src\hadoop-common-project\hadoop-common\src\main\winutils\libwinutils.vcxproj]
```

So, I tried to run just this command

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Bin\midl.exe" /W2 /WX /nologo /char signed /env x64 /Oicf /app_config /outC:\hadoop-2.7.0-src\hadoop-common-project\hadoop-common\target/winutils/ /h hadoopwinutilsvc_h.h /tlb C:\hadoop-2.7.0-src\hadoop-common-project\hadoop-common\target/winutils/libwinutils.tlb /robust hadoopwinutilsvc.idl"
```

Now I get the following error

```
64 bit Processing .\hadoopwinutilsvc.idl
hadoopwinutilsvc.idl
midl : command line error MIDL1001 : cannot open input file oaidl.idl
```

When I searched for the file oaidl.ild. I found it in folder

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Include
```

I included this in the PATH and ran the command again with the same error. I noticed that the file name is 'OAIdl.Idl' and not 'oaidl.idl'.

The first line in the file hadoopwinutilsvc.idl is 'include oaidl.idl'.

**Does this mean that these is an error in hadoop source?**

END UPDATE - Original question below.

I am trying to build hadoop on Windows 7 x64.
I keep getting the following error.
I have provided the relevant stack trace below. Any help will be much appreciated.
The command I ran on the command prompt is 
 `mvn package -Pdist,native-win -DskipTests -Dtar`

```
[DEBUG] env: PATH=C:\csvn\bin\;C:\csvn\Python25\;C:\Program Files\CollabNet\Subversion Client;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\system32\wbem;C:\Windows\system32\windowspowershell\v1.0\;c:\program files\ibm\gsk8\lib64;c:\program files (x86)\ibm\gsk8\lib;C:\IBM\WEBSPH~1\APPSER~1\db2\BIN;C:\IBM\WEBSPH~1\APPSER~1\db2\FUNCTION;C:\IBM\WEBSPH~1\APPSER~1\db2\SAMPLES\REPL;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Program Files (x86)\CMake\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Users\ajayamrite\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\apache-maven-3.3.3/bin;C:\cygwin64\bin;C:\protoc-2.5.0-win32;C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Bin;C:\hadoop\bin;c:\hadoop\sbin;C:\Program Files (x86)\CMake\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin\x86_amd64
[DEBUG] env: PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC
[DEBUG] env: PLATFORM=x64
[DEBUG] env: PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE=AMD64
[DEBUG] env: PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=Intel64 Family 6 Model 70 Stepping 1, GenuineIntel
[DEBUG] env: PROCESSOR_LEVEL=6
[DEBUG] env: PROCESSOR_REVISION=4601
[DEBUG] env: PROGRAMDATA=C:\ProgramData
[DEBUG] env: PROGRAMFILES=C:\Program Files
[DEBUG] env: PROGRAMFILES(X86)=C:\Program Files (x86)
[DEBUG] env: PROGRAMW6432=C:\Program Files
[DEBUG] env: PROMPT=$P$G
[DEBUG] env: PSMODULEPATH=C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\
[DEBUG] env: PUBLIC=C:\Users\Public
[DEBUG] env: PYTHONHOME=C:\csvn\Python25\
[DEBUG] env: SESSIONNAME=Console
[DEBUG] env: SYSTEMDRIVE=C:
[DEBUG] env: SYSTEMROOT=C:\Windows
[DEBUG] env: TEMP=C:\Users\AJAYAM~1\AppData\Local\Temp
[DEBUG] env: TMP=C:\Users\AJAYAM~1\AppData\Local\Temp
[DEBUG] env: USERDOMAIN=bedouinvm
[DEBUG] env: USERNAME=ajayamrite
[DEBUG] env: USERPROFILE=C:\Users\ajayamrite
[DEBUG] env: WDIR=C:\
[DEBUG] env: WINDIR=C:\Windows
[DEBUG] env: ZLIB_HOME=C:\zlib127-dll
[DEBUG] Executing command line: [msbuild, C:\hadoop-2.7.0-src\hadoop-common-project\hadoop-common/src/main/winutils/winutils.sln, /nologo, /p:Configuration=Release, /p:OutDir=C:\hadoop-2.7.0-src\hadoop-common-project\hadoop-common\target/bin/, /p:IntermediateOutputPath=C:\hadoop-2.7.0-src\hadoop-common-project\hadoop-common\target/winutils/, /p:WsceConfigDir=../etc/hadoop, /p:WsceConfigFile=wsce-site.xml]
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
Build started 5/27/2015 3:13:28 PM.
Project "C:\hadoop-2.7.0-src\hadoop-common-project\hadoop-common\src\main\winutils\winutils.sln" on node 1 (default targets).
ValidateSolutionConfiguration:
  Building solution configuration "Release|x64".
Project "C:\hadoop-2.7.0-src\hadoop-common-project\hadoop-common\src\main\winutils\winutils.sln" (1) is building "C:\hadoop-2.7.0-src\hadoop-common-project\hadoop-common\src\main\winutils\winutils.vcxproj.metaproj" (2) on node 1 (default targets).
Project "C:\hadoop-2.7.0-src\hadoop-common-project\hadoop-common\src\main\winutils\winutils.vcxproj.metaproj" (2) is building "C:\hadoop-2.7.0-src\hadoop-common-project\hadoop-common\src\main\winutils\libwinutils.vcxproj" (3) on node 1 (default targets).
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(297,5): warning MSB8003: Could not find WindowsSDKDir variable from the registry.  TargetFrameworkVersion or PlatformToolset may be set to an invalid version number. [C:\hadoop-2.7.0-src\hadoop-common-project\hadoop-common\src\main\winutils\libwinutils.vcxproj]
InitializeBuildStatus:
  Touching "C:\hadoop-2.7.0-src\hadoop-common-project\hadoop-common\target/winutils/libwinutils.unsuccessfulbuild".
Midl:
  C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Bin\midl.exe /W2 /WX /nologo /char signed /env x64 /Oicf /app_config /out"C:\hadoop-2.7.0-src\hadoop-common-project\hadoop-common\target/winutils/" /h "hadoopwinutilsvc_h.h" /tlb "C:\hadoop-2.7.0-src\hadoop-common-project\hadoop-common\target/winutils/libwinutils.tlb" /robust hadoopwinutilsvc.idl 
TRACKER : error TRK0002: Failed to execute command: ""C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Bin\midl.exe" /W2 /WX /nologo /char signed /env x64 /Oicf /app_config /outC:\hadoop-2.7.0-src\hadoop-common-project\hadoop-common\target/winutils/ /h hadoopwinutilsvc_h.h /tlb C:\hadoop-2.7.0-src\hadoop-common-project\hadoop-common\target/winutils/libwinutils.tlb /robust hadoopwinutilsvc.idl". The handle is invalid. [C:\hadoop-2.7.0-src\hadoop-common-project\hadoop-common\src\main\winutils\libwinutils.vcxproj]


Done Building Project "C:\hadoop-2.7.0-src\hadoop-common-project\hadoop-common\src\main\winutils\libwinutils.vcxproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.
Done Building Project "C:\hadoop-2.7.0-src\hadoop-common-project\hadoop-common\src\main\winutils\winutils.vcxproj.metaproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.
Done Building Project "C:\hadoop-2.7.0-src\hadoop-common-project\hadoop-common\src\main\winutils\winutils.sln" (default targets) -- FAILED.

Build FAILED.

"C:\hadoop-2.7.0-src\hadoop-common-project\hadoop-common\src\main\winutils\winutils.sln" (default target) (1) ->
"C:\hadoop-2.7.0-src\hadoop-common-project\hadoop-common\src\main\winutils\winutils.vcxproj.metaproj" (default target) (2) ->
"C:\hadoop-2.7.0-src\hadoop-common-project\hadoop-common\src\main\winutils\libwinutils.vcxproj" (default target) (3) ->
(PrepareForBuild target) -> 
  C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(297,5): warning MSB8003: Could not find WindowsSDKDir variable from the registry.  TargetFrameworkVersion or PlatformToolset may be set to an invalid version number. [C:\hadoop-2.7.0-src\hadoop-common-project\hadoop-common\src\main\winutils\libwinutils.vcxproj]


"C:\hadoop-2.7.0-src\hadoop-common-project\hadoop-common\src\main\winutils\winutils.sln" (default target) (1) ->
"C:\hadoop-2.7.0-src\hadoop-common-project\hadoop-common\src\main\winutils\winutils.vcxproj.metaproj" (default target) (2) ->
"C:\hadoop-2.7.0-src\hadoop-common-project\hadoop-common\src\main\winutils\libwinutils.vcxproj" (default target) (3) ->
(Midl target) -> 
  TRACKER : error TRK0002: Failed to execute command: ""C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Bin\midl.exe" /W2 /WX /nologo /char signed /env x64 /Oicf /app_config /outC:\hadoop-2.7.0-src\hadoop-common-project\hadoop-common\target/winutils/ /h hadoopwinutilsvc_h.h /tlb C:\hadoop-2.7.0-src\hadoop-common-project\hadoop-common\target/winutils/libwinutils.tlb /robust hadoopwinutilsvc.idl". The handle is invalid. [C:\hadoop-2.7.0-src\hadoop-common-project\hadoop-common\src\main\winutils\libwinutils.vcxproj]

    1 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:01.36
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Main ................................. SUCCESS [  1.558 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Project POM .......................... SUCCESS [  1.334 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Annotations .......................... SUCCESS [  2.580 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Assemblies ........................... SUCCESS [  0.170 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Project Dist POM ..................... SUCCESS [  2.133 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Maven Plugins ........................ SUCCESS [  2.585 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop MiniKDC .............................. SUCCESS [  2.008 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Auth ................................. SUCCESS [  3.022 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Auth Examples ........................ SUCCESS [  2.663 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Common ............................... FAILURE [ 22.818 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop NFS .................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop KMS .................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Common Project ....................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop HDFS ................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop HttpFS ............................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop HDFS BookKeeper Journal .............. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop HDFS-NFS ............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop HDFS Project ......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-yarn ........................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-yarn-api .................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-yarn-common ................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-yarn-server ................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-yarn-server-common .......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-yarn-server-nodemanager ..................... SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-yarn-server-web-proxy ....................... SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-yarn-server-applicationhistoryservice ....... SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-yarn-server-resourcemanager ................. SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-yarn-server-tests ........................... SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-yarn-client ................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-yarn-server-sharedcachemanager .............. SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-yarn-applications ........................... SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-yarn-applications-distributedshell .......... SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-yarn-applications-unmanaged-am-launcher ..... SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-yarn-site ................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-yarn-registry ............................... SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-yarn-project ................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-mapreduce-client ............................ SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-mapreduce-client-core ....................... SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-mapreduce-client-common ..................... SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-mapreduce-client-shuffle .................... SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-mapreduce-client-app ........................ SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-mapreduce-client-hs ......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient .................. SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-mapreduce-client-hs-plugins ................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop MapReduce Examples ................... SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-mapreduce ................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop MapReduce Streaming .................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Distributed Copy ..................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Archives ............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Rumen ................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Gridmix .............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Data Join ............................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Ant Tasks ............................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Extras ............................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Pipes ................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop OpenStack support .................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Amazon Web Services support .......... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Azure support ........................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Client ............................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Mini-Cluster ......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Scheduler Load Simulator ............. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Tools Dist ........................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Tools ................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Distribution ......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 43.747 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-05-27T15:13:30+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 68M/306M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.3.1:exec (compile-ms-winutils) on project hadoop-common: Command execution failed. Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.3.1:exec (compile-ms-winutils) on project hadoop-common: Command execution failed.
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:216)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:862)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:286)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:197)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Command execution failed.
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.execute(ExecMojo.java:303)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal(DefaultExecutor.java:402)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute(DefaultExecutor.java:164)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.executeCommandLine(ExecMojo.java:750)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.execute(ExecMojo.java:292)
    ... 22 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :hadoop-common
```

Answer (score 9):

I'm also trying to build hadoop 2.7.1 on Windows 7 x64.

For the question at UPDATE-2:

I have downloaded the file "**ammintrin.h**" and puted it in: "**C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include**" (I don't have Visual Studio, only installed Windows SDK 7.1)

It worked for me without installing  Microsoft Visual Studio Service Pack 1.

Here there is the file: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/uploaded_files/735/ammintrin.m
(Notice that you have to rename with the .h extension)

Comment: I was trying to build C++ project using VS2010 SDK and I have VS2017 installed. I was facing same issue,  my error also got resolved by copying file from above link. Installing and Uninstalling SDK, vsredist didn't help. thanks.