# Hadoop on Windows Building/ Installation Error

Tags: windows, hadoop, msbuild, building

I am trying to install [Apache Hadoop 2.7.1](https://hadoop.apache.org/)  on Windows x64 (8.1 and Server 2012 R2), but I am failing at goal:

```
    [INFO] Apache Hadoop Common ............................... FAILURE [ 37.925 s]
```

In the past days, I think I followed the steps of all tutorials, like [HadoopOnWindows](https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/Hadoop2OnWindows), or [this one](http://www.srccodes.com/p/article/38/build-install-configure-run-apache-hadoop-2.2.0-microsoft-windows-os). I did all the prerequisites, but as I Googled, the relevant ones for my problem are the following:

- Set path to MSBuild.exe like: *C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319;* in Path
- Set path to [CMake](http://www.cmake.org/)
- Install Microsoft SDK 7.1 and Run with its Microsoft SDK 7.1 CMD
- Tried to build: *hadoop-common\src\main\winutils\libwinutils.sln* and *hadoop-common\src\main\winutils\winutils.sln* with Visual Studio 2013, but building fails due to compiling errors. Visual Studio 2010 doesn't even want to open them. I do not know how to correct the compile errors (in case this is the problem)

**Other ppl, similar problem**
Some of the similar topics I am following are these: [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30485525/missing-ammintrin-h-when-compiling-hadoop-on-windows), [two](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/hadoop-user/201406.mbox/%3CCALyLaQLFZ5YyuB7c0FCnvnW5dhO+D-3F+A805zKT9k=SAy0tiA@mail.gmail.com%3E), [three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28411053/hadoop-windows-org-codehaus-mojoexec-maven-plugin), [four](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20592050/build-hadoop-2-2-on-windows).  I mainly tried all the suggestions, but it still breaks.

**Error**

```
    [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Total time: 01:11 min
    [INFO] Finished at: 2015-07-08T15:18:29+02:00
    [INFO] Final Memory: 69M/269M
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.3.1:exec (c
    ompile-ms-winutils) on project hadoop-common: Command execution failed. Process
    exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]
    [ERROR]
    [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e swit
    ch.
    [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
    [ERROR]
    [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea
    d the following articles:
    [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionE
    xception
    [ERROR]
    [ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command

    [ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :hadoop-common
```

**Help**
I have no idea what to do next, I feel like I tried everything. Please help me solve this error and continue with the Hadoop install on Windows.

**UPDATE 1**
Looking on the error stack more closely, I saw that the file *Microsoft.Cpp.props* was not found. Moreover, the entire folder *Program Files (x86)/MSBuild* was missing. Thus, I installed Visual Studio 2010 and it fixed this problem.

Of course, a new problem arise. I am able to build *libwinutils*, but not *winutils*. I get many *LNK2001* errors:

```
Error   48  error LNK1120: 18 unresolved externals  C:\hdfs\hadoop-common-project\hadoop-common\src\main\winutils\x64\Release\winutils.exe  winutils
Error   36  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol BuildServiceSecurityDescriptor    C:\hdfs\hadoop-common-project\hadoop-common\src\main\winutils\service.obj   winutils
Error   32  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ChownImpl C:\hdfs\hadoop-common-project\hadoop-common\src\main\winutils\service.obj   winutils
Error   40  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol CreateEnvironmentBlock    C:\hdfs\hadoop-common-project\hadoop-common\src\main\winutils\task.obj  winutils
Error   44  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol CreateLogonTokenForUser   C:\hdfs\hadoop-common-project\hadoop-common\src\main\winutils\task.obj  winutils
Error   41  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol DestroyEnvironmentBlock   C:\hdfs\hadoop-common-project\hadoop-common\src\main\winutils\task.obj  winutils
Error   37  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol EnableImpersonatePrivileges   C:\hdfs\hadoop-common-project\hadoop-common\src\main\winutils\service.obj   winutils
Error   34  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol GetSecureJobObjectName    C:\hdfs\hadoop-common-project\hadoop-common\src\main\winutils\service.obj   winutils
Error   38  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol KillTask  C:\hdfs\hadoop-common-project\hadoop-common\src\main\winutils\service.obj   winutils
Error   43  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol LoadUserProfileForLogon   C:\hdfs\hadoop-common-project\hadoop-common\src\main\winutils\task.obj  winutils
Error   35  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol LogDebugMessage   C:\hdfs\hadoop-common-project\hadoop-common\src\main\winutils\service.obj   winutils
Error   46  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol LookupKerberosAuthenticationPackageId C:\hdfs\hadoop-common-project\hadoop-common\src\main\winutils\task.obj  winutils
Error   31  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol MIDL_user_allocate    C:\hdfs\hadoop-common-project\hadoop-common\src\main\winutils\hadoopwinutilsvc_s.obj    winutils
Error   30  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol MIDL_user_free    C:\hdfs\hadoop-common-project\hadoop-common\src\main\winutils\hadoopwinutilsvc_s.obj    winutils
Error   47  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol RegisterWithLsa   C:\hdfs\hadoop-common-project\hadoop-common\src\main\winutils\task.obj  winutils
Error   33  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol SplitStringIgnoreSpaceW   C:\hdfs\hadoop-common-project\hadoop-common\src\main\winutils\service.obj   winutils
Error   42  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol UnloadProfileForLogon C:\hdfs\hadoop-common-project\hadoop-common\src\main\winutils\task.obj  winutils
Error   45  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol UnregisterWithLsa C:\hdfs\hadoop-common-project\hadoop-common\src\main\winutils\task.obj  winutils
Error   39  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol wsceConfigRelativePath    C:\hdfs\hadoop-common-project\hadoop-common\src\main\winutils\service.obj   winutils
```

**UPDATE 2**
The answer from @tiho solved the problem mentioned above (and I am very thankful, as it took me 4 days already). Now, a fresh new problem, at goal:

```
[INFO] Apache Hadoop KMS .................................. FAILURE [  1.531 s]

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.7:run (dist) on project hadoop-kms: An Ant BuildException has occured: java.net.UnknownHostException: archive.apache.org
[ERROR] around Ant part ...<get dest="downloads/apache-tomcat-6.0.41.tar.gz" skipexisting="true" verbose="true" src="http://archive.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-6/v6.0.41/bin/apache tomcat-6.0.41.tar.gz"/>... @ 5:182 in C:\hadoop-2.7.1-src\hadoop-common project\hadoop-kms\target\antrun\build-main.xml: Unknown host archive.apache.org.
```

I found a lame work-around to the problem above. I manually downloaded it, added to the folders:

*C:\hadoop-2.7.1-src\hadoop-common-project\hadoop-kms\downloads*
*C:\hadoop-2.7.1-src\hadoop-hdfs-project\hadoop-hdfs-httpfs\downloads*
and deleted from the files:
*C:\hadoop-2.7.1-src\hadoop-common-project\hadoop-kms\target\antrun\build-main.xml*
*C:\hadoop-2.7.1-src\hadoop-hdfs-project\hadoop-hdfs-httpfs\target\antrun\build-main.xml*
the following lines of code:

```
<mkdir dir="downloads"/>
  <get dest="downloads/apache-tomcat-6.0.41.tar.gz" skipexisting="true" verbose="true" src="http://archive.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-6/v6.0.41/bin/apache-tomcat-6.0.41.tar.gz"/>
```

Note that I am also using proxy, I have set the proxy in the *settings.xml*, and set PATH to MAVEN_OPTS as suggested in the same answer from @tiho. Is this the problem? besides the options suggested there, I have also added password and username to the MAVEN_OPTS.

Note that I can access: [http://archive.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-6/v6.0.41/bin/apache-tomcat-6.0.41.tar.gz](http://archive.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomca%20t-6/v6.0.41/bin/apache-tomcat-6.0.41.tar.gz) using my browser.

But I am still curious how to solve the issue correctly, because this problem continues to appear, and I need to do the same work-around again.

**Update 3**
That being said, the happiest moment of this week:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 21:05 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-07-10T11:33:17+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 228M/672M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Did you try asking on serverfault.com?

Comment: nope. why would I ask there and should I replicate this post there ?

Comment: Not sure. But if you don't get the answer here, maybe there you would be able to get help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Took me the whole day to manage to build it... Microsoft has obviously lots of issues with backward compatibility. It would help if Hadoop would move to a more recent toolchain.

Here are the key steps I had to perform (beyond those mentioned in the doc). This is using the Windows SDK compiler rather than VS 2010 (it is supposed to be possible with VS 2010 but I haven't tried it):

1. Uninstall Visual Studio 2013 (I would recommend uninstalling any Visual Studio >= 2010) -- this is to get rid of error `MSBUILD : Configuration error MSB4146: Cannot evaluate the property expression "$([MSBuild]::ValueOrDefault('$(VCTargetsPath)','$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V120\'))"`
2. Uninstall Visual Studio C++ 2010 Redistributable (x64 + x86) -- to avoid [Error when installing windows SDK 7.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19366006/error-when-installing-windows-sdk-7-1)
3. Uninstall fully .NET Framework 4.5 -- to avoid [Failure during conversion to COFF: file invalid or corrupt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12267158/failure-during-conversion-to-coff-file-invalid-or-corrupt)
4. Reboot
5. Install .NET Framework 4.0
6. Install Windows SDK 7.1

I added to my PATH (in the Windows SDK shell) the bin folder of my Git installation (for GNU tools), the bin folder of CMake, and the folder containing protoc.exe. In addition (but most people should not need it), I had to setup Maven to use my HTTP proxy, first editing `settings.xml` as indicated in Maven's documentation, but also by defining the environment variable `MAVEN_OPTS=-Dmy.proxy.host -Dhttp.proxyPort=my.proxy.port`, as otherwise there was a timeout at some point during the build.

Note that I noticed a good amount of warnings during the build: I suspect some of them to be caused by using the Java SDK 1.8 instead of 1.7. However after finally seeing a `BUILD SUCCESS` I didn't feel like trying again with 1.7.

Comment: Hi Tiho, thanks for your detailed explanation. Unfortunately I am experience the unresolved external symbol explained above. I followed the directions posted but still have no luck. 
Visual studio 2010, java 1.8, windows 10 32 bit, hadoop 2.6
I cannot build the winutils and the other library with VS. 
It should be a problem with the set up of my systems. I don't think I have to fix any source code, it may be a missconfiguration problem.
Any comment will be highly appreciated.
Kind Regards, 
Paul

Comment: @PlayingWithBI I'm afraid I can't say more than what I posted above, I haven't reallly tried any alternate setup myself. But I see you mention VS 2010 while I personally uninstalled it and used the Windows SDK compiler instead. Maybe you could give it a shot as well?

Answer (score 8):

I've managed to build it with Visual Studio 2015 community edition.

Here's how I've built it:

My environment

Here's my shopping list:

> - Windows 10
> - JDK 1.8.0_51
> - Maven 3.3.3
> - Findbugs 1.3.9 (I haven't used this)
> - ProtocolBuffer 2.5.0 (I didn't pick the latest and greatest    here - it has to be 2.5.0)
> - CMake 3.3.0
> - Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition
> - GnuWin32 0.6.3 - a bit painful to install but so is cygwin
> - zlib 1.2.8
> - internet connection

Windows System Environment variables

> - JAVA_HOME = "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_51"
> - MAVEN_HOME=c:\apache-maven-3.3.3

(make sure you point the above to your JDK version and maven installation)

I appended the following to my windows system environment Path variable:

> ;%MAVEN_HOME%\bin;C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319;c:\zlib

The weird "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319" path is the location of MSBuild.exe, which is required during the build process.

**Protoc Buffers 2.5.0**

Oh no, another unix/linux only build? I've downloaded the google package named protoc-2.5.0-win32.zip. Then extracted the binary file (protoc.exe) to  c:\windows\system32 - just a lazy way to put it on the path.

I'm not 100% sure of the effect of having a win32 component for this win64 build. But:
"Hadoop 0.23+ requires the protocol buffers JAR (protobufs.jar) to be on the classpath of both clients and servers; the native binaries are required to compile this and later versions of Hadoop." - http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ProtocolBuffers.

So I understand the win32 executable is used only during the build process (the jar equivalent should be packaged in the build).

If it is used in any way to compile native code, we may have left with some pointers out of order. I'll come back to this when I can.

**Tweaking the Hadoop sources**

Well, this was necessary to allow to build to execute. It shouldn't affect the quality of the build itself, but let's keep in mind the result is an unofficial, unsupported, use at your own risk hadoop, intended for a development environment.

Migrating VS projects

The following files need to be open with Visual Studio 2015:

\hadoop-common-project\hadoop-common\src\main\winutils\winutils.vcxproj
\hadoop-common-project\hadoop-common\src\main\native\native.vcxproj

Visual Studio will complain of them being of an old version. All you have to do is to save all and close.

Enabling cmake VS 2015 project generation for hdfs

On the line 441 of \hadoop-hdfs-project\hadoop-hdfs\pom.xml, edit the else value as the following:

> <condition property="generator" value="Visual Studio 10" else="Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64">

(the "value" value applies to win32 - you may want to edit it if building for win32).

**Building it**

You should try and find on windows the "Development Command Prompt for VS2015". I'm still wondering what is so special about this, but the fact is that it will only work with that.

More Environment variables
Those should be done on the command prompt:

> set Platform=x64
>
> set ZLIB_HOME=C:\zlib\include (unlike the official instructions, this should be pointing to the include folder).

Finally building it

Go to the hadoop source folder and issue:

> mvn package -Pdist,native-win -DskipTests -Dtar

**What next?**

Follow the official docs to get your hadoop instance configured and up and running.

I'll try to keep a link with for the binaries on my blog:

> http://kplitzkahran.blogspot.co.uk/2015/08/hadoop-271-for-windows-10-binary-build.html

Comment: Really helpful answer! I successfully build hadoop on VS2015 + Windows 10 with the help of this answer.

Comment: In Hadoop 3.0.1 package file '\hadoop-hdfs-project\hadoop-hdfs\pom.xml' don't have any property to set Visual Studio version. Any idea in this?

Answer (score 2):

I successfully built Hadoop 3.0.2 with Visual Studio 2017 on Windows 10.

Here is my settings look like:

1. Windows 10
2. Visual Studio 2017 Community Version
3. Maven 3.5.0
4. JDK 1.8.0_144
5. Cmake 3.10.0-rc1
6. ProtocolBuffer 2.5.0
7. Cygwin

First I open these two solution files in VS 2017 and save.

```
hadoop-3.0.2-src\hadoop-common-project\hadoop-common\src\main\winutils\winutils.sln
```

and

```
hadoop-3.0.2-src\hadoop-common-project\hadoop-common\src\main\native\native.sln
```

This will migrate those two projects from VS 2010 to VS 2017.

Second I need to change line 141 of the pom file located at

```
D:\hadoop-3.0.2-src\hadoop-hdfs-project\hadoop-hdfs-native-client\pom.xml
```

to

```
<condition property="generator" value="Visual Studio 10" else="Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64">
```

This will ensure VS 2017 will be used during the building process.

I have also encountered a problem where MSBuild complains the command is long then stops working, I think this is related to the Maven default repository location. To fix this, I added following line

```
<localRepository>D:/maven_repo</localRepository>
```

to file

```
apache-maven-3.5.0\conf\settings.xml
```

to move the Maven repository to a new location (in this case `D:/maven_repo`).

Finally I opened the `x64 Native Tools Command Prompt for VS 2017`, `cd` to the hadoop source folder and issued following command:

```
mvn clean package -Pdist,native-win -DskipTests -Dtar -Dmaven.repo.local=D:\maven_repo
```

I spend more than 10 hours to fix all problems, hopefully my solution will help others as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to share my experience in building Hadoop 3.1.2 on Windows 8.1. I spent a lot of time fixing build errors, but all I needed was 'Building on Windows' section in Building.txt file in root folder of Hadoop sources.

I used "x64 Native Tools Command Prompt for VS 2017".

So, here are my steps

1. Read '\hadoop-3.1.2-src\Building.txt', section 'Building on Windows'.

This actually may be sufficient to figure out what you need to do, but with VS 2017 the process is a bit different.

2. Put sources into short path to avoid 'the command line is too long' error.

I used `d:\hdp\` folder

3. As it's stated in Building.txt, set up environment using '\hadoop-3.1.2-src\dev-support\win-paths-eg.cmd'.

When you use Native Tools, you don't need a CALL command at the end of the .cmd file, so comment it out:

```
@REM CALL "%MSVS%\VC\vcvarsall.bat" %VCVARSPLAT%
```

My settings looks like this:

```
SET Platform=x64
SET VCVARSPLAT=amd64

@REM ******************
@REM Forcibly move the Maven local repo
@REM (use short path to avoid 'the command line is too long' error)

SET MAVEN_OPTS=-Dmaven.repo.local=D:\.m2

@REM *******************************************
@REM
@REM Locations of your bits and pieces
@REM
@REM NOTE: cmake is assumed to already be on the
@REM command path
@REM (it's true when you use Native Tools Command Prompt)

SET MAVEN_HOME=%MAVEN_HOME%
SET JAVA_HOME=%JAVA_HOME%
@REM SET MSVS=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional
SET PROTO_BIN=D:\tools\protoc-2.5.0-win32
SET GIT_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Git
set ZLIB_HOME=D:\tools\zlib-1.2.11

SET PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%MAVEN_HOME%\bin;%PROTO_BIN%;%GIT_HOME%\bin;%PATH%

@REM CALL "%MSVS%\VC\vcvarsall.bat" %VCVARSPLAT%
```

Off course you need Java, Maven, ProtoBuf, Git and ZLib to be installed in the paths listed above.

4. Run "x64 Native Tools Command Prompt for VS 2017"

From within "x64 Native Tools Command Prompt for VS 2017" navigate to Hadoop's source folder, run your 'win-paths-eg.cmd' and start building with Maven:

```
d:
cd D:\hdp
D:\hdp\dev-support\win-paths-eg.cmd
mvn package -Pdist,native-win -DskipTests -Dtar
```

5. Wait ~30-40 minutes.

That's all, folks!