# Zlib's zconf.h is Not seen by Visual Studio even though Windows System Variables has valid variable

Tags: c++, visual-studio, hadoop, zlib

I'm trying to build the following hadoop version on development computer with Windows 10 Home Edition

hadoop-2.7.3-src

Here are the details about my local development environment:

-Windows 10 Home Edition

-Intel Core i5-6200U CPU @2.30GHz

-RAM 16 GB

-64-bit Operating System, x64-based processor

-Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015 Version 14.0.25431.01 Update 3

-.NET Framework 4.6.01586

-cmake version 3.7.2

-CYGWIN_NT-10.0 LTPBCV82DUG 2.7.0(0.306/5/3) 2017-02-12 13:18 x86_64 Cygwin

-java version "1.8.0_121"

-Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_121-b13)

-Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.121-b13, mixed mode)

-Apache Maven 3.3.9 (bb52d8502b132ec0a5a3f4c09453c07478323dc5; 2015-11-10T11:41:47-05:00)

-Google Protocol Buffers protoc --version libprotoc 2.5.0

-I downloaded Zlib zlib version 1.2.11 source code, and built zlib

The zconf.h file is located in the directory C:\zlib\builtzlib

In Windows System Environment Variables, I defined ZLIB_HOME variable with the value C:\zlib\builtzlib

[image]

After researching online, someone said that the following Visual Studio solution file needs to be built successfully in Visual Studio:

....\hadoop-2.7.3-src\hadoop-common-project\hadoop-common\src\main\native\native.sln

However, as soon as I open the native.sln solution, I get the error that zconf.h is undefined even though Visual Studio is aware of the ZLIB_HOME Windows System Environment variable:

[image]

How can I make native.sln build successfully without any errors?

Comment: A couple of ideas here - restart VS after setting the variable. Also I'm not convinced those variable expansions correspond to environment variables.

Comment: The answer in this other posting solved my problems:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42869261/hadoop-build-failing-in-windows-zconf-h-is-missing-from-native-sln